# How to rotate a PNG image using ExifTool?

Tags: png, orientation, exiftool

I am trying to rotate PNG images using [exiftool](https://ExifTool.org/) using following command line:

```
exiftool -Orientation=3 -n ImageName
```

The command line run successfully in terminal and I can get the Orientation info via command line: `exiftool -Orientation -n ImageName`, saying `3` in this case. But the PNG image itself doesn't rotate at all.
This command line works fine with JPG and TIFF image. So how to rotate a PNG image using exiftool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that tool, but bear in mind:

1) you are not really rotating the image, you are (at best) setting a metadata property that (might) suggest to an image reader a different orientation than the default.

2) how image readers (including web browsers) interpret metadata when showing an image can be quite unpredictable.

3) PNG has little or [no EXIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg/9576717) metadata support.

I don't know what metadata ("chunk", in PNG vocabulary) that program writes into the PNG image when you tell it to change the "orientation", but I would not be surprised if only that program can read that. You can use this [tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) to peek inside the PNG chunks.

Why don't you do a "real" image rotation?

Comment: Thank you! My program tries to decide whether a PNG is rotated via the Orientation value. It turns out I went to the wrong way. I will try other ways.