# How can I extract GPS EXIF info from a PNG?

Tags: gps, png, exif

I have approx 1000 PNG photographs which I am told have GPS information stored within them. I have tried numerous web based / downloadable programs to try and extract the EXIF information so I can get the GPS info.

I had some success with EXIF tool but there is no GPS info within:
[image]

Is there some other extraction method that I should be trying or is there no GPS info in the photograph?

Comment: PNG has not EXIF info. 
Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg/9576717

Comment: @leonbloy - There are other ways to store GPS.  PNG supports XMP, which is another standard way to store GPS information.  Also, PNG is able to store EXIF in non-standard ways.  ExifTool supports writing EXIF to PNG images using the ImageMagick "Raw profile type APP1" technique.