# Is there a standard for writing GPS data to a PNG?

Tags: gps, location, png, metadata

I know that PNG doesn't support EXIF metadata (see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492969/how-can-i-extract-gps-exif-info-from-a-png) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg)) but it does support its own format of [Chunks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks) including text as a "name=value" pair. However, I can't find any standard for the naming of text apart from these basic [keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo).

There's a reference in the second question to this failed [standard](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/exif/drafts/d020.html) from 2000 which defines fields like:

- GPSAltitude
- GPSAltitudeRef
- GPSInfo
- GPSLatitude
- GPSLatitudeRef
- GPSLongitude
- GPSLongitudeRef
- GPSMapDatum
- GPSVersionID

and they seem to be used in this [discussion](https://github.com/xbgmsharp/piwigo-openstreetmap/issues/14). Should I just use these or is there an official standard I can use?