# Is there a way to read/write XMP metadata using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, metadata, xmp, exiftool

I would like to read/write XMP metadata in JPEG and PNG files.

I'm able to do this using the [exiftool](https://ExifTool.org/)

```
~ $ exiftool -xmp-dc:description="FooBar" sample.png
    1 image files updated
~ $ exiftool sample.png | grep "Description"
Description                     : FooBar
```

However, I'm not able to read the XMP Metadata using imagemagick

```
~ $ identify -verbose sample.png | grep "Description"
```

My reason to write XMP metadata is that so it can be read by Adobe Products.

**Question**

- Is there a way to read/write XMP metadata using imagemagick?

Comment: Off topic, but compatibility with Adobe products isn't the only reason to want to manipulate XMP metadata.                                                                                                               http://www.metadataworkinggroup.org/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf

Comment: png doesn't support metadata --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg

Comment: That's only with regards to EXIF metadata (though Exiftool and Exiv2 have a workaround).  PNG does support XMP metadata https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform#Location_in_file_types

*Edit:* Bah, didn't check the dates

Answer (score 1):

What you want to ask is "does ImageMagick support reading or writing XMP (descriptive) metadata?". The answer to that question, from reading [the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php), is no. ImageMagick reads (almost) all metadata from a file, but not descriptive metadata.

If for some reason you must use ImageMagick to extract XMP metadata, you could try to include a filter. [Filters can be configured](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php) to process image files, but they are not part of ImageMagick itself.

Answer (score 1):

convert -ping yourimage.jpg XMP:-

Answer (score 0):

Access XMP data can be done as follows:

```
ImageMagick.XmpProfile xmp = image.GetXmpProfile();

Console.WriteLine("\n\n----> xmp:" + xmp);
if (xmp != null)
{
    you have to process the XML data of the XMPs result.  
    ie. use XPATH or some other XML interface.
}
```