# How to write metadata in a PNG or a GIF file?

Tags: php, metadata, gd

I use php GD library to create images and I need to attach a basic text string to each images. I know that the PNG and GIF format doesn’t support EXIF but I wonder if any trick could replace it. I am interested in any possible solution.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576717/967168) states it is possible to embed metadata chunks in a PNG. So now just need to know how to do that using GD image library.

Answer (score 0):

I think most softwares that can handle XMP writing can write XMP metadata to PNG files because XMP is the only metadata format that PNG supports. On top of my head the softwares I can think of are Picasa, XnView, and Daminion, all free (Daminion server version not free).
For GIF I'm not sure, but I know it only 'partially' supports XMP.

Comment: PNG added support for EXIF metadata in July 2017: http://ftp-osl.osuosl.org/pub/libpng/documents/pngext-1.5.0.html#C.eXIf