# PictureBox that takes into Account EXIF Orientation Tag and Final Image Rotation

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, exif, system.drawing

The Picturebox control in c# does not take into account the EXIF Orientation tag for images.So the images appear in the wrong orientation.I intent to solve this problem by reading the EXIF data and manually rotating the Image.But processing the image with exif orientation tag is a problem.Since the user may choose any output format and if i assume right **only JPEG and TIF support EXIF**.So the final processed image should be manually rotated rather than adding the EXIF Tag.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Not very current but [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg) for a discussion of png. What other formats do you expect and what exactly is the workflow? Also: Even with EXIF dta present there may well be a reason to let the user correct the rotation, e.g. when the foto was shot straight up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is mostly correct.
Orientation tags are supported in JFIF (plain JPEG), TIFF (countless sub-types) and the 2 types of Exif (JPEG-compressed and single-page uncompressed TIFF). Almost all other common image formats do **not** support it, but that depends on how you define *common*.
[This post](http://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/CS/forums/42411/showpost.aspx) discusses some ways developers can handle similar situations.
Although the discussion is about LEADTOOLS, the design logic behind the 3 options discussed is valid regardless of the classes or functions you use to handle your images.