# How to extract exif data from a PNG photo?

Tags: python, png, exif, exiftool, pyexiv2

I am on OSX, running python and trying to extra EXIF data from a large set of images in my library.
I've been using `Pillow` so far with my JPG photos and it works like a charm.

However, I stumbled on the first `PNG` photo I hit.

I am able to view a lot of the EXIF data on Mac though, using the photo inspector.

First, it seems that Pillow doesn't support `__get_exif` on PNGs. 
Then I tried switching into `pyexiv2`, but that one hits an installation issue.
`exiftool` also didn't work for me.

Any idea whether there is a python way of extracting EXIF data on OSX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. PNG standard  just started supporting EXIF in 2017 so **make sure it's EXIF** and not other metadata chunks that look like EXIF. [See this Stack overflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg) for details.
2. You can use [PyExifTool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) to extract EXIF data.
3. If you want to use a GUI you can use [PyExifToolGui](https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI/).
4. **Make sure you have the latest version of the command line
   [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)** which recently added PNG EXIF support.
5. You say that ExifTool doesn't work for you but don't give any
   details on what your issues are and perhaps you just need to update
   your version. From the [previously referenced thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24916466/3525475) the ExifTool author states ExifTool supports PNG EXIF:

> The PNG group has recently been considering adding a new "eXIf" and/or
>   "zXIf" chunk to store EXIF information. ExifTool 10.43 added support
>   for "exIf" and "zxIf" chunks in support of this. – PhilHarvey May 26
>   '17 at 14:49