# extract exif orientation data from image

Tags: javascript, html, jpeg, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing JPEG EXIF rotation data in Javascript on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side)

I'd need to extract the orientation EXIF data from an HTML JPEG image with Javascript.

according to [exiftool's documentation](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html) the orientation flag is found at offset 0x112 within the EXIF marker, and occupies 2 bytes.

I guess we just need to extract the data at good offset and 'convert' the value but i don't have any idea how to achieve this in the browser. The result value should be a number between 1 and 8 describing the orientation.

How to read that data from a simple IMG tag ?
I need a webkit only solution, but browser only.

Thanks !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side).

thanks. here's the final code example to get orientation :

```
var b64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA......";
var bin = atob(b64.split(',')[1]);
var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(bin));
alert(exif.Orientation);
```

Comment: when i try this it alerts undefined for me.... please help

Comment: what do you have if you console log exif ?

Comment: heres a test page :  http://metapicz.com/

Comment: Guys I used the same code but I'm getting an error saying "mystore.html:408 Uncaught ReferenceError: BinaryFile is not defined"...Any idea how to resolve it??

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer managed to get such a positive score without saying that this code depends on [exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js/blob/master/exif.js), and I'm not sure what this *BinaryFile* is supposed to be.

Comment: I get undefined for 'BinaryFile'

Comment: Is there a way to *short circuit* this? As in, get the exif without having to read the **whole file**?

Comment: I get undefined for 'BinaryFile'