# How can show image in proper orientation, Landscape or portrait

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am having a file input control on the page to select an image.
When user selects an image, I am showing image on the page.

But my problem is, when user selects a vertical or portrait image it is displayed in landscape mode.

So, how can I detect image orientation & apply proper css to show in Landscape or Portrait view.

Comment: Can't you calculate if width is larger than height is landscape and the other way around? Based on that you can create two classes with the respective style.

Comment: Do you mean, a photo that is displayed in a desktop image viewer one way is being displayed differently in your app? This might be due to EXIF data not being read or being interpreted incorrectly. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side

Comment: @BenPhilipp I tried the solution you posted but that giving me exception as  Uncaught ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined

Comment: Mind you, they are using external libraries there. But did I interpret your problem correctly?

Comment: @BenPhilipp yes you did. They have mentioned external library for "BinaryFile" but not for EXIF.   I got another JS library that gives me EXIF referece

Answer (score 1):

Step #1:

Check if the image's width is bigger than its heigth. Then you'll figure out that the image is a landscape image. You can check it quickly using javascript.

Step #2:

Create a CSS and apply it using a class (apply the class using javascript) for whatever orientation you need.