# Why am I receiving ReferrenceError: BinaryFile is not Defined

Tags: javascript, exif

I'm following the result in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7585267) exactly but I am receiving the following error:

> ReferenceError: BinaryFile is not defined

Here's the code where that is used:

```
fr.onloadend = function() {
            console.log(this);
            exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(this.result));
        }
```

The `console.log` shows that there is data there, I just don't understand this error I'm receiving.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing

Comment: https://github.com/jseidelin/binaryajax/blob/master/binaryajax.js

Answer (score 4):

I used the following which worked very well

```
EXIF.getData(img, function() {
    orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
});
```

where `img` is my image object.

Also `EXIF.pretty(this)` was helpful to see what data is in each image.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `BinaryFile` and changing how FileReader read the file (`readAsArrayBuffer`) worked for me.

```
fileReader.onload = function (event) {

    var exif = fileReader.readFromBinaryFile(this.result);

    console.log(exif);

};

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```