# Does canvas ImageData in JavaScript contain EXIF info?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, exif, getimagedata

From the Docs

*ImageData interface represents the underlying pixel data of an area of a canvas element*

I would like to know does ImageData will have only pixel data or pixel data + meta data? Meta data means any EXIF data like orientation, resolution, file type or dpi.

**Problem**

Whenever I draw images with EXIF Orientation other than 1 to canvas and read it back as ImageData, the resulted ImageData is not properly aligning on Image tag when I am converting ImageData to DataURL.

Issue is observed both in mobile as well as desktop browsers all most all browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<canvas>` does not preserve any JPEG metadata, as this metadata is specific to JPEG file itself. Canvas, by definition, is raw pixel data only.

- [Parse JPEG file yourself to extract metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side)
- Play with canvas
- [Use a custom encoder to write JPEG file out of canvas, injecting extracted EXIF metadata back.](https://github.com/gchudnov/inkjet)

Comment: Does inkjet helps in manipulating EXIF data? i.e changing DPI or resolution values?

Comment: By "play with canvas" I mean "do whatever canvas operations you want to do with your javascript"

Comment: is there any method which can be used to save metadata along with image data before using `canvas.toDataUrl()`.