# CSS image-orientation: from-image; Not working

Tags: css

My images orientation on my website are not the same as the actual image, I tried using: `image-orientation: from-image;` to fix my issue and it did not work, the images orientations are wrong and when I inspect the element, `image-orientation: from-image;` is crossed out....is there another way to do this?

Comment: The compatibility table for this feature clearly states it is not supported by many browsers yet (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation). The only other option is to do it yourself and rotate any image, or you could use something like php to read the image, get the rotation data, rotate the image and return the finished image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very technical, we need to read the image as raw binary data.

I hope that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side) will help you.