# PHP - How to compress a user uploaded image to a specific size

Tags: php, image

I have a website where users can upload images for their profile. Since our resources are limited, the images need to be under a certain size. However I do not want to force users to upload images only under that size. I was wondering if it is possible in php to compress an image of any size to a certain specific size.
Looking at other SA questions it seems like the only thing similar is:

```
imagejpeg($tn, $save, 75);
```

However with this if an image is HUGE it will still only be compressed to 75% and a really small image is going to lose even more quiality.

So my question is: **Is it possible to compress an image of *any* size to another specific size?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of compression, can you try resizing their image to a set size? I.e if they tried uploading an image 500x500, you would resize it to 80x80. Take a look at [imagescale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php).

Comment: [You may review the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696187/php-how-to-compress-images-without-losing-visible-quality-automatically?rq=1) I hope it helps.

Comment: You can set maximum width / height on the images; maintain the aspect ratio, and optimize them to save on resources.  Dave Chen's suggestion is appropriate.  You can also see another question on the maximum size of an image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806091/maximum-file-size-of-jpeg-image-with-known-dimensions

Comment: Then you can calculate the correct aspect ratio with some division. However I recommend just scaling to a set value. If you start caring about the same aspect ratio, someone could upload an image 1x5000 or 5000x1. If it's a profile avatar, it should be standardized for everyone anyways.

Comment: Oh right. But would the file size be decreased?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [imagecopyresampled?](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

Answer (score 0):

I use phpThumb for exactly this purpose - http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

```
include("phpthumb.class.php");  

$image_destination = '/path/to/destination/file.jpg';

$phpThumb = new phpThumb();

$phpThumb->setSourceFilename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$phpThumb->setParameter('w', 400);
$phpThumb->setParameter('h', 400);      

$phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail();
$phpThumb->RenderToFile($image_destination);
```

The advantage of using this is that you can specify parameters that control how the image will be output, for example:

> w: width of the image
>
> h: height of the image
>
> zc: zoom into the centre of the image
>
> far: force aspect ratio
>
> iar: ignore aspect ratio

You can specify just `w` and then the height will be calculated automatically whilst maintaining the aspect ratio. You can see all the parameters at http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt